# calling a function to return an array - type mismatch

Tags: vba, excel

I have a custom type as shown below,

```
Public Type TypeFieldColumn
    iCol As Integer
    dRow As Double
End Type
```

I then have the following sub routine

```
Private Sub PopulateWorksheet()

Dim wsTS As Worksheet
Dim clsData As New clsDatabase
Dim rsTS As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim Fields() As TypeFieldColumn

Set wsTS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SomeName)
Set rsTS = clsData.SomeMethod()

Fields = FindFactorColumns(rsTS, wsTS)

End Sub
```

which calls the function below

```
Private Function FindFactorColumns(rsTS As ADODB.Recordset, wsTS As Worksheets) As TypeFieldColumn()

Dim i As Integer
Dim index As Integer
Dim FactorName As String
Dim Flds() As TypeFieldColumn

ReDim Flds(1 To rsTS.Fields.Count - 1)

For i = 1 To rsTS.Fields.Count - 1                      
    FactorName = rsTS.Fields(i).Name
    index = MapBloombergIndexToFactorName(FactorName)
    If index > 0 Then FactorName = pMap(index).MapName

    Flds(i).iCol = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(FactorName, wsTS.Range("1:1"), 0)
 Next

 FindFactorColumns = Flds

 End Function
```

I get a run time error of type mismatch on the line Fields = FindFactorColumns(rsTS, wsTS) - I don't understand why though?

Comment: Your function declaration is wrong - you want `wsTS As Worksheet` and not `wsTS As Worksheets`

Comment: Thanks! I wondered why that wasn't working spent a long time looking but obviously not closer enough!

Comment: As a programmer one of the hardest things is often to see what you *actually* wrote rather than what you think you wrote. ;)

Comment: Hey @Rory, I'll write something up from your comment as an answer if you're not planning to.

Answer (score 0):

Only writing this up to save @Rory time, it is his answer.

The type mismatch occurred because wsTS, which was saved as a single worksheet in the Populate Worksheet Sub, was declared as multiple worksheets in the FindFactorColumn function.

Because the error line occured at the function call, @Rory was able to determine the type mismatch by looking at the type of the variables used in the Function and comparing them to the type of those same variables when saved in the Sub.